# Problem Fitting Model in Tidymodels: Error: ! Can't use NA as column index with `[` at positions 3 and 4:\

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, tidymodels

I am writing a project in `Tidymodels`. I have created a `train` and `test` set, set out a `recipe` and a `model`. When I call `workflow()`, add the `recipe` and `model`, then call `fit(data = df_train`, I am getting the following error.

```
Error:
! Can't use NA as column index with `[` at positions 3 and 4.
```

I am on R version 4.1.3 and R Studio 2022.02.0 Build 443.

For reproducibility, here is the workflow. Note that the data is on GitHub so you will need an internet connection to load the data.

```
## Load package manager

if(!require(pacman)){
  
  install.packages("pacman")
  
}

## Load required packages. Download them if they do not exist in my system.

pacman::p_load(tidyverse, kableExtra, skimr, knitr, glue, GGally, 
               
               corrplot, tidymodels, themis, stargazer, rpart, rpart.plot, 
               
               vip, patchwork, data.table)
```

The next step will load the data.

```
df <- fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Karuitha/data_projects/master/employee_turnover/data/employee_churn_data.csv') %>%

  mutate(left = factor(left, levels = c("yes", "no")))
```

Next, I slice the data into a training and test set and create a recipe.

```
## Create a split object consisting 75% of data
split_object <- initial_split(df, prop = 0.75, 
                              
                              strata = left)

## Generate the training set
df_train <- split_object %>%
  
  training()

## Generate the testing set
df_test <- split_object %>%
  
  testing()

###############################################
## Create a recipe
df_recipe <- recipes::recipe(left ~ ., 
                             
                             data = df_train) %>%
  
  ##We upsample the data to balance the outcome variable
  themis::step_upsample(left, 
                        
                        over_ratio = 1, 
                        
                        seed = 500) %>%
  
  ##We make all character variables factors
  step_string2factor(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  
  ##We remove one in a pair of highly correlated variables
  ## The threshold for removal is 0.85 (absolute) 
  ## The choice of threshold is subjective. 
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors(), 
            
            threshold = 0.85) %>%
  
  ## Train these steps on the training data
  prep(training = df_train)
```

Next, I define a model and attempt to fit.

```
## Define a logistic model
logistic_model <- logistic_reg() %>%
  
  set_engine("glm") %>%
  
  set_mode("classification")
```

Then fit it.

```
workflow() %>% 
  
  add_recipe(df_recipe) %>% 
  
  add_model(logistic_model) %>% 
  
  fit(data = df_train)
```

This is where I get the error

```
Error:
! Can't use NA as column index with `[` at positions 3 and 4.
```

I have checked and rechecked. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am responding to my own question.

One thing I have realised is that the problem is in the `recipe` step. When I replace `step_str2factor` with `step_dummy`, then everything works fine.

I still do not know why this is the case. Maybe I will need to study Tidymodels more keenly!!

Answer (score 2):

In `df_recipe`, remove `prep(training = df_train)` i.e. define it like so:

```
## Create a recipe
df_recipe <- recipes::recipe(left ~ .,
                             data = df_train) %>%
  ##We upsample the data to balance the outcome variable
  themis::step_upsample(left,
                        over_ratio = 1,
                        seed = 500) %>%
  ##We make all character variables factors
  step_string2factor(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  ##We remove one in a pair of highly correlated variables
  ## The threshold for removal is 0.85 (absolute)
  ## The choice of threshold is subjective.
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors(),
            threshold = 0.85)
```

Removing `prep()` resulted in no errors when I ran fit(). I believe `prep()` is not needed here because `workflow()` does the same thing.

From the help message `?workflow`:

```
When you specify and fit a model with a workflow(), parsnip and workflows match and reproduce the underlying behavior of the user-specified model’s computational engine.
```

From `?prep()`:

```
 If you are using a recipe as a preprocessor for modeling, we highly recommend that you use a workflow() instead of manually estimating a recipe (see the example in recipe()).
```

When should you use `prep()` then? From my experience, it's helpful when you want an idea how your data will look like post-processing:

```
#how training data will look like after your recipe steps are applied
df_recipe %>% 
  prep() %>% 
  bake(new_data = NULL)
# A tibble: 10,134 x 9
   department  promoted review projects salary tenure satisfaction bonus left 
   <fct>          <int>  <dbl>    <int> <fct>   <dbl>        <dbl> <int> <fct>
 1 operations         0  0.578        3 low         5        0.627     0 no   
 2 sales              0  0.676        3 high        5        0.578     1 no   
 3 admin              0  0.620        4 high        5        0.687     0 no   
 4 sales              0  0.653        4 low         6        0.679     0 no   
 5 sales              0  0.642        3 medium      6        0.623     0 no   
 6 support            0  0.563        4 medium      5        0.559     0 no   
 7 engineering        0  0.799        3 medium      5        0.433     1 no   
 8 marketing          0  0.611        3 low         6        0.502     0 no   
 9 sales              0  0.567        3 medium      6        0.845     0 no   
10 finance            0  0.583        3 medium      6        0.608     0 no   
# ... with 10,124 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, Desmond for finding time to reply. I appreciate. I have taken note of this matter.